# Problems with ValidationPipe in NestJS when I need to validate the contents of an array

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I have a situation where my client user can enter zero or multiple addresses. My problem is that if he enters an address, some fields need to be mandatory.

**user.controller.ts**

```
@Post()
@UsePipes(ValidationPipe)
async createUser(
    @Body() createUser: CreateUserDto,
) {
    return await this.service.saveUserAndAddress(createUser);
}
```

**create-user.dto.ts**

```
export class CreateUserDto {
    @IsNotEmpty({ message: 'ERROR_REQUIRED_FULL_NAME' })
    fullName?: string;

    @IsNotEmpty({ message: 'ERROR_REQUIRED_PASSWORD' })
    password?: string;

    @IsNotEmpty({ message: 'ERROR_REQUIRED_EMAIL' })
    @IsEmail({}, { message: 'ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL' })
    email?: string;

    ...

    addresses?: CreateUserAddressDto[];
}
```

**create-user-address.dto.ts**

```
export class CreateUserAddressDto {
    ...

    @IsNotEmpty()
    street: string;

    ...
}
```

`CreateUserDto` data is validated correctly and generates `InternalServerErrorResponse`, but `CreateUserAddressDto` data is not validated when there is some item in my array. Any idea how I can do this validation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nest fw uses `class-transformer` to convert a json to a class object. You have to set the correct type for the sub-attribute if it is not a primitive value. And your attribute is an array, you have to config to tell `class-validator` that it is an array, and validate on each item.

Let's update `CreateUserDto`

```
import { Type } from 'class-transformer';
import { ..., ValidateNested } from 'class-validator';

export class CreateUserAddressDto {
    ...


    @ValidateNested({ each: true })
    @Type(() => CreateUserAddressDto)
    addresses?: CreateUserAddressDto[];

    ...
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks   :)

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is - to basically add logic to primitive validators provided out of the box with nest - aka - defining a custom validator.

This can be done by using the two classes `ValidatorConstraint` and  `ValidatorConstraintInterface` provided by the class validator.

In order to sort this, transform the incoming input / club whatever data you want to validate at once into an object - either using a pipe in nestjs or sent it as an object in the API call itself, then attach a validator on top of it.

#### To define a custom validator:

```js
import { ValidatorConstraint, ValidatorConstraintInterface } from 'class-validator';


/**
 * declare your custom validator here
 */
@ValidatorConstraint({ name: 'MyValidator', async: false })
export class MyValidator implements ValidatorConstraintInterface {
  
   /** return true when tests pass **/
   validate(incomingObject: myIncomingDataInterface) {
    try {
     // your logic regarding what all is required in the object
     const output = someLogic(incomingObject);
     return output;
    } catch (e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  defaultMessage() {
    return 'Address update needs ... xyz';
  }
}
```

Once you have defined this, keep this safe somewhere as per your project structure. Now you just need to call it whenever you want to put this validation.

**In the data transfer object**,

```js
// import the validator
import { Validate } from 'class-validator';
import { MyValidator } from './../some/safe/place'

export class SomeDto{
    @ApiProperty({...})
    @Validate(MyValidator)
    thisBecomesIncomingObjectInFunction: string;
}
```

As simple as that.